# Avoiding getting 0 equals 0 in geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question

In geometry problems, I aways set up various equations and then when I find something that is the same in two equations, I isolate it and set the remaining parts equal. E.g. if I have $a^2x+b^2=c$ and $bx^2=a^2c+b^2$ I will do $a^2=(c-b^2)/x=(bx^2-b^2)/c$. However, oftentimes (far too often in fact) this results in $0=0$ when I simplify the $(c-b^2)/x=(bx^2-b^2)/c$ equation, and $0=0$ doesn't give any new information (apart from the fact that the two equations were equivalent, even if they looked different). Unfortunately, the algebra required to reduce to $0=0$ is usually long, and by that time I've probably lost interest in the problem and I usually give up when I end up with $0=0$. How can I avoid setting up equivalent equations in geometry problems? Is there a secret trick that is quick to tell if two operations on the diagram will yield equivalent equations, or is it just experience/intuition that will allow me to avoid this type of mistake?

In other words, how can I know which operations I have to perform on the diagram (cosine rule, sine rule, pythagoras' theorem, etc) to yield equations that each contribute some new piece of information, rather than beign equivalent to each other?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

This normally comes from the fact that there is a dependence between your equations.  You think you have three equations in three unknowns, but really you only have two.  This can happen as you are solving when you add and subtract the equations in dependent combinations.